# Laravel Check column using relationship column

Tags: php, sql, laravel, lumen

I need to query and check if the relationship column is the same in my main table column.

example codes:

***not working***

```
User::with('product', => function($q) {
                $q->whereRaw('users.company_id',' product.company_id');
            })->get();
```

***not working***

```
User::with('product', => function($q) {
                $q->whereRaw('users.company_id = product.company_id');
            })->get();
```

***not working***

```
User::with('product')->whereColumn('users.company_id', 'product.company_id')->get();
```

but it's not working..
any idea how to do it?

My Models

***User Model***

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id');
}
```

***Product Model***

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'product_id');
}
```

Comment: Could you show us all the models (User, product and company) and show us the file/function you are trying to edit it in. If the answer doesn't work

Comment: it's just an example models. 
but the codes the same in my codes.

Comment: What about your company model? If you don't have 1 I would suggest you make one makes the relation stuff easier.

Answer (score 2):

Please try again:

```php
User->with(['product' => function ($query) {
    $query->join('users', 'users.company_id', '=', 'product.company_id');
}])->get();
```

Comment: as much as possible I don't want to use join in this situation.

Comment: I tried it, and the result was changed or wrong, the query remove users record that doesnt have product.

Comment: the query is correct, but if you can see my Product Model, product model has many users, so if I use join inside product query the query response become longer. in my side from 1290ms change to 3.0s. 
anyway I upvote your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `DB:raw()` then show the table info? like [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-columns.html)